# ¿Por qué es posible ofrecer recompensas a preguntas que ya tienen respuesta aceptada?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Mi pregunta es una duda simple y a la vez pudiera considerarse como solicitud de "característica nueva" como bien dice la etiqueta.

La pregunta es la siguiente:

**¿Por qué es posible ofrecer recompensas a preguntas que ya tienen respuesta aceptada?**

Creo que sería mejor si se eliminara la opción de "Ofrecer recompensa" en caso de que la pregunta ya tenga una respuesta aceptada.

O si está bien como está, entonces agradecería que me expliquen por que se puede hacer esto.

Answer (score 6):

Creo que todo parte del concepto de **Respuesta aceptada**. Esta es la respuesta que le sirve al OP en el caso puntual en un momento determinado. No significa que sea la mejor, simplemente que esa respuesta fue la que el OP aceptó.

Pero puede ocurrir que a otro usuario le interese una respuesta distinta a la aceptada, como una alternativa. En este caso, la recompensa busca atraer la atención hacia la pregunta.

También puede ser que existan respuestas mejores, ya porque son más completas, ya porque producen mejores resultados, puede ser que sean más pertinentes, etc. 
La recompensa también puede ser un reconocimiento a una respuesta que según el criterio del usuario sea merecedora de los puntos.

¡Eso es genial! ¿No crees? Es una excelente forma de crear contenido de calidad.  Por un lado se promueve la creación y por otro se reconoce el esfuerzo. Es además algo muy divertido, perseguir recompensas, competir con los mejores y ¡ganas medallas!

Cuando tengas oportunidad, otorga una recompensa. Puedes hacerlo a una pregunta tuya (para buscar mejores respuestas) o una pregunta de otro (para reconocer una buena respuesta). Y por supuesto, trata de ganar alguna, entre más las usemos, poco a poco aparecerán recompensas para más etiquetas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya he ofrecido recompensas pero en el sitio en inglés, lamentablemente perdí los puntos y nadie respondió porque resulta que la pregunta no tenía solución posible, por lo menos hasta ahora. Por otra parte... entiendo lo que explicas, pero sigo sin verle mucho sentido aún, ya que la recompesa al final se la gana el que le marcaron el aceptado, no es así? Me explico con un ejemplo en otro comentario porque no me cabe en este.

Comment: Ejemplo: Si yo ofreciera una recompensa a una pregunta que ya tiene respuesta aceptada buscando otra respuesta que sea mejor para mi, no tiene sentido porque el OP ya marcó su aceptada y no va a cambiar su opinion porque yo di una recompensa, por lo tanto no voy a conseguir que me den más respuestas ya que la recompensa ya ha sido otorgada a otro usuario.

Comment: Continuando... En ese caso lo que yo haría, en lugar de ofrecer una recompensa, sería publicar otra pregunta, haciendo referencia a la original y explicando qué quiero adicional y por qué queiro una respuesta diferente a la que ya existe para demostrar que no es un duplicado. No se si me explico bien. Pero por eso es que sigo sin verle el sentido...

Comment: El que pone la recompensa selecciona al ganador. No recuerdo quién gana si no se elige uno explícitamente, seguramente nadie, pero seguro qué hay una faq sobre eso.

Comment: Ah ya, eso no lo sabia, pensaba que la respuesta aceptada era la que se llevaba todos los puntos.... sí, si mal no recuerdo creo que le dan una parte a la respuesta con mas votos

Comment: @toledano Buena respuesta. Agregaría un motivo más: darle más visibilidad (publicidad) a publicaciones que pasaron desapercibidas

Comment: @Adriana el funcionamiento de las recompensas está detallado también en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty (si te interesa ver todas las reglas). Además, cada recompensa que ofrezcas te va a dejar agregar un comentario personalizado de por qué estás ofreciendo, o qué estás buscando